# TableView data from search not updated properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire

I made a TableView with Swift where I show Search results of the Query that's filled in the UiTextField.

```
let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:SearchCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifier) as! SearchCell
    cell.objectName.text = self.search_results_list[indexPath.section]
    return cell
}
```

On the *Value Changed*-event I trigger the Search action:

```
 @IBAction func searchInputChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    self.search_results_list = []
    let search = self.searchField.text
    let parameters: Parameters = ["api_token": token, "search": search!+" "]
    let URL = "https://myweb.app/api/search"
    Alamofire.request(URL, parameters: parameters).responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[SearchResponse]>) in
        let searchResultsArray = response.result.value
        if let searchResultsArray = searchResultsArray {
            for searchResult in searchResultsArray {
                self.search_results_list.append(searchResult.description!)
            }
        }
        // Then I reloeadData of the TableView
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And the NumberOfSections method:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.search_results_list.count
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
```

It does work, but when I fill in the form quickly, the Array has the correct order, but the TableView has a different order. When I inspect the Array I see that the order IS correct, but the TableView shows a different one. When I wait for a second and add a space at the end, the TableView does show the correct order. 
The same when I add letter by letter and wait after each letter that the tableview is reloaded, the output is correct

What am I missing?

Comment: A potential issue is that if you tap quickly "ab", you'll do a search for "a", then a search for "b". But since the calls are async, you server might responds quickly for "ab", and then for "a", and so your results are wrong because it's only for "a" while your current text is "ab".

Comment: @Larme I checked the server and the input is send correctly, it shows the correct value. But indeed, it looks like that a new output is already given but not yet rendered or something by Swift

Comment: @AshleyMills that doesn't do the trick at all

Comment: this needs a stack, add the requests to , and ignore response if it's not from the top most item

Comment: @Sh_Khan I don't get what you mean, can you please explain it more briefly? Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like they said in the comments. It's probably because the asynchronous calls are returning at different times. And most probably the one with **fewer results** (newer calls) will come back **faster** than the ones that have **more results** (older calls). So what you have to do is **invalidate** every API response which **doesn't match** your **current search text**.

```
@IBAction func searchInputChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    self.search_results_list = []
    let search = self.searchField.text
    let parameters: Parameters = ["api_token": token, "search": search!+" "]
    let URL = "https://myweb.app/api/search"
    Alamofire.request(URL, parameters: parameters).responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[SearchResponse]>) in
        if search == self.searchTextField.text {             // Compare search text with current text in searchTextField.
            let searchResultsArray = response.result.value
            if let searchResultsArray = searchResultsArray {
                for searchResult in searchResultsArray {
                    self.search_results_list.append(searchResult.description!)
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**IMPORTANT OPTIMIZATION TIP**

You can wrap your API call in a **timer** so that it is hit only when the user stops entering characters into the text field. This helps **avoid unnecessary API calls**. You can achieve this by using a `Timer` to make the network calls. Start the timer in `textDidChange` and invalidate it if the delegate is called again within a short duration (0.5s or whatever you feel is optimal)

Comment: WAUW, looks like this easy fix is THE solution! Thanks :)

Comment: And thanks for the tip; fixed that too :) @rakesha-shastri

Comment: Why the "DispatchQueue" by the way? Just curious what that does, because it also works without it

Comment: @user1469734 API calls run on the background thread and if you are calling UI operations inside their closures (which will still be in the background thread), they won't behave properly. UI calls should **always** be invoked on the main thread.